# Email the filter results from Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following function (btw I am new to Google Apps Scripts).

```
function testing(){
  let thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(thirtyMinuteWorksheet).getDataRange().getValues()

  let filterData = thisSpreadsheet.filter(function (row,index) {
      return row[11] >= 30
  });


if(filterData.length > 0){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: 'email@gmail.com',
      subject: 'test',
      body: filterData,
      noReply: true
      });
  }
```

the filter data filters the sheet and returns all the rows that match the logic.  Id like to be able to email those rows.   if I run this, i get and email with this. (plus more, shorten it for simplicity).

```
{10=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7f7f43f6, 179=[Ljava.lang.Object;@d387470, 
83=[Ljava.lang.Object;@5daa185f, 54=[Ljava.lang.Object;@39ca2a17, }
```

i can see this is an object but I couldnt find anything on their API that pointed me in the right direction as to how to covert this results into the actual values

ps

Yes, if i console.log filterData i do get the correct objects.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way, since this is an array of objects, I just converted that into and HTML function.  as below.

I passed in my array results and added some headers as well.

```
function makeTableHTML(myArray,tableHeaders) {
    let result = "<table border=1>";
    result += "<tr>";
        for(var j=0; j<tableHeaders.length; j++){
            result += "<td>"+tableHeaders[j]+"</td>";
        }
        result += "</tr>";
    for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        result += "<tr>";
        for(var j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++){
            result += "<td>"+myArray[i][j]+"</td>";
        }
        result += "</tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";

    return result;
}
```

That gave me a way to add the return results into the sendmail function from Google Scripts.

Comment: great answer. That also works if you want it in table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `join` instead since the data you are sending is an array. Convert it to string to properly show the data.

**Sample data:**

[image: sample data]

**Code:**

```
  let filterData = thisSpreadsheet.filter(function (row, index) {
    return row[11] >= 30;
  });

  // Preprocesses filterData before sending mail
  filterData.forEach(function (row, index) {
    filterData[index] = filterData[index].join(",");
  });
  filterData = filterData.join("\n");


  if (filterData.length > 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: 'email@gmail.com',
      subject: 'test',
      body: filterData,
      noReply: true
    });
  }
```

**Sample output:**

[image: sample output]

One quick answer is to try and wrap `filterData` with `JSON.stringify()`, but you can't modify how it shows in the mail.

**Code:**

`body: JSON.stringify(filterData),`

**Sample output:**

[image: sample output2]

Comment: Thank you, but the Java object i believe is just a misinterpretation the script not know what to do with it.  I figured out a way.   ill post my answer shortly.